ArXiv DOI and publication
I have submitted a paper to arXiv but it has been declined for the following reason:

Dear arXiv user,
Previously, our moderators requested that you only submit articles that have already appeared in a mainstream conventional journal. This article does not contain a valid journal reference or DOI (that resolves to a journal's website).
Therefore, your article has been declined.

So I created a DOI with zenodo: zenodo10.5281/zenodo.13785388
Is this a good way to do it? Will arXiv now accept the new version of my submission?

Hmmm, does your DOI resolve to a journal's website? The message you got seems unusual. Perhaps it has to do with dissatisfaction with your previous submissions. Is that the case?

I have already published 4 articles to arXiv and they never asked a DOI.

My paper has been declined. So the problem is solved. Thank you for your help!


our moderators requested that you only submit articles that have already appeared in a mainstream conventional journal

I believe this is a request because you've sent them a lot of junk in the past, and they are tired of your abuse of their archive.
Zenodo is not a mainstream conventional journal. It's not a journal at all. It's not that arXiv needs you to provide them with a DOI because they have some special need for DOIs. Instead, arXiv is tired of vetting your junk and only has the patience to deal with your next submission if you've gotten someone else to vet it already. The important part of their request to complete/fix is "already appeared in a mainstream conventional journal" not "This article does not contain a ... DOI".
If you do not understand what a journal is, it is unlikely that you are producing content that is appropriate for arXiv. You likely need a mentor in research to do any useful research. See also I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank? which is relevant even if you do not believe you have solved a famous open problem.

The problem stated by arXiv is that "This article does not contain a valid journal reference or DOI (that resolves to a journal's website)".
Zenodo is not a journal, so creating a Zenodo DOI will not address this problem.
